# Angular 7: Send response message from service

Tags: javascript, html, angular, http, service

I make request from service file in my Angular project:

```
signIn(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {

    const formData = ...
        this.http.post(`${this.uri}`, formData, httpOptions)
          .subscribe(res => console.log(        
              if (statusCode === '0') {
                this.message = 'test';

              } else {
                this.message2 = 'test2';
              }
            })));
        return;
      }
```

This function works very well. But I cannot shot my `message` in my HTML. When I type {{message}} in HTML, its undefined. 
I declared `message: String;` but its not work.
I guess services are private and this problem is so.

How can I show my response in HTML? What is the best way?

UPDATED: This is my component:

```
message: String;

signIn(username, password): Observable<any> {

    this.cookieService.deleteAll();

    this.ls.signIn(username, password).subscribe(res =>
      xml2js.parseString(res, function (err, result) {
        const statusCode = ...
        console.log(statusCode); // it getting statusCode
        if (statusCode === '0') {
          this.message = 'test'; //Potentially invalid reference access to a class field via 'this.' of a nested function
        } else {

        }
      }));
      return;
  }
```

Comment: what is `statusCode` here?

Comment: Its not important because my condition is works. I can get response in console if statusCode equal to 0 or not.

Comment: I think problem ralate with useing `console.log(` in subscribe. Try change in to lambda function

Answer (score 1):

You can not access component fields in service. You need to pass response of service by some way and then only you can use that response and based on that assign value to message and display in your html.

I think you should use callback in which you'll wrap your http request's response and will use at outer layer of service.

```
signIn(username: string, password: string, data:any) {
    const formData = ...
    this.http.post(`${this.uri}`, formData, httpOptions)
        .subscribe(response => {
        data(response);
    }, error => data(// do something here);
}
```

**now use this as something like this(at component I think):**

```
message: String;

this.restService.signIn(userName, password, response => {
    if(response && response.hasOwnProperty('statusCode')) {
        if (response['statusCode'] === '0') {
           this.message = 'test';    
        } else {
           this.message = 'test2';
        }
    }
});
```

**now you can use message in html**

```
{{message}}
```

**NOTE**

You should always use service layer for data transfer only(if it is rest/api service), business logic or data manipulation should be used at some intermediate service or component level.

At this way you can make generic rest service and use across application, you just need to pass request body, url and response callback object.

If you're going to write logic in service then you'll have to write separate service for each api call.

Comment: This answer works. With this you can execute the API call in the service with the subscribe method, and still return the response in the controller if needed. However, what is the type of data:any parameter? It is better to replace 'any' with a more specific type.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your sample code is part of a service class : you cannot access service attributes like message or message2 from your HTML template.
You have to return HTTP observable to the controller and put the subscribe logic in your controller.

Service:

```
return this.http.post(`${this.uri}`, formData, httpOptions);
```

Controller:

message: String;

signIn(username, password): Observable {

```
this.cookieService.deleteAll();

this.ls.signIn(username, password).subscribe(res =>
  const self = this;
  xml2js.parseString(res, function (err, result) {
    const statusCode = ...
    console.log(statusCode); // it getting statusCode
    if (statusCode === '0') {
      self.message = 'test'; 
    } else {

    }
  }));
  return;
```

}

Comment: Thank you. I tried this method (I think you're right) but now getting 'subscribe undefined' error in component.

Comment: in your post the "return" statement is not correct, so it leads to the subscribe undefined error

Comment: Thanks. This is the last one: Run the code and: "Potentially invalid reference access to a class field via 'this.' of a nested function"

Comment: This could be because of bad use of console.log : can you add to your post the code of the controller ?

Comment: Updated my question with component.

Comment: please try with my update : const self = this; .... self.message = 'test';

Answer (score 0):

Angular templates will search variables only in component which we are declared in them. So do changes like below in your template

`<p> {{service.message}} </p>`

Here the `service` is which you are injected into your component.

If you are declare `message:string` in your service that's fine, by default variables are public and we can access them in templates. But with the help of service variable which we are injected them through constructor.

I hope this will solve your issue :)